# Windows server is restarting by itself each 2 minutes

Tags: windows-server-2008, restart

I am going crazy. My windows server 2008 r2 keep restarting by itself each 2 minutes. I cannot see the view logs.. Pls suggest what can be performed.. I saw the fixing in registry part but for me I am very fresh there .. And our system is life...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Start in Safe Mode to see if you can get control.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/cc61d7d5-100c-493f-bd9b-d0d1241fc155/windows-server-2008-r2-restarts-automatically?forum=winservergen)?

> To Stop automatic restart of server please un-check the marked option
>   in below snap shot. Also try to boot server in safe mode and check for
>   the similar kind of issue? Another useful step is go to run and type
>   msconfig|startup|uncheck startup items which are not required.

[image]